# how to apply shuffle animation on recyclerview when its shuffling

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I apply shuffle on recycler view on button click event, and its working, but when I click on button,  images shuffle it's position, but there is no effect appear when its shuffling, how do I make shuffle animation, help me please, thank you.

here is my code:

```
public class GridRecycleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       /*toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);*/
        suffle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.suffle);

        for (int i = 0; i < Glob.imgs.length; i++) {
            data.add(new ImageData(Glob.imgs[i]));
        }


        try {
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleGridView);
            //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(4, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            suffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Collections.shuffle(data);
                    adapter = new Recycle_Adapter(mContext, data);
                    recyclerView.swapAdapter(adapter, false);
                    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new FlipInBottomXAnimator());
                    recyclerView.getItemAnimator().setMoveDuration(5000);
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

i already apply some other animation, but its not look good on shuffle, i want Shuffle animation, how do i do that. Thank you in Advance